# postscript printing image misaligned

Tags: 16.04, printing, postscript

I'm printing to Lexmark Z2420 using another linux machine because my xubuntu 16.04 laptop cannot install the printer, no driver is available. When I print from the other linux machine the print appears on paper exactly as on the screen. This is important if I print labels, etc. I have to access the Lexmar printer from my xubuntu laptop from the other linux machine if I need to print color. Lexmark is set up on my xubuntu with Generic Postscriptprinter driver (POSTSCRI.PPD). The problem is that print image on the paper is shifted by 1/4 inch to the right and up. I tried to adjust the ppd file in /etc/cups/ppd folder, but it has no effect on printer output. On the other linux machine I was able to place the print image correctly aligned to the edges of paper so that printing is correct as I stated in the beginning. How can I achieve the same result in xubuntu? Nota Bene: there is a debian install package from Lexmark prepared for 10.10 but it does not work on xubuntu 16.04. This is why I have to print via the other linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the precise answer but it is an adequate solution to the printing problem: I changed my printer setting to raw queue and now the page prints correctly, same as on the server linux machine. Apparently the postscript driver has its own (incorrect in my case) page settings.